# Does the PayPal gateway allow a user to transfer money to a PayPal account using net banking?

Tags: c#, paypal, onlinebanking

I worked on Paypal Gateway integration on the client's website where

Payment request get generated
- User get transfer to his/her Paypal account
- there he completes his transaction via either through card or PayPal balance or bank attached to his/her account.
- we do get a proper response as well.

Currently, the system working finely. Now **we want to add a facility to pay via net banking to a merchant's PayPal account**. I tried to search on the net to get lead for this but did not found any.
do anyone had implemented this, right now I dont have any code to post it here.

Comment: You need to integrate with a service which provides gateway to banks payment services...

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya do you have any reference where i can start to r&d..